# Grails 3.3 - how to set the URIEncoding of the embedded tomcat in development mode in yml config file

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am trying to set up my development environment to support UTF-8 URI encoding. I have found that the correct option for spring boot embedded tomcat container should be `server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8` but I have no success of setting this in the yml config file. I also tried to pass the option as a parameter with `-D` option, but still no success. I did a lot of searching but there is simply no documentation how to set this on grails 3.3. Does anyone have idea how can this option in embedded tomcat in development mode?

Answer (score 0):

The setting in the YML file would look like:

```
server.tomcat.uri-encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: I already tried this but it doesn't seem to be working for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that utf-8 encoding is fine in grails 3.3. The problem turned out that I need to decode the uri using

```
def uri = URLDecoder.decode(request.getRequestURI().trim(),"UTF-8")
```

this is all and problem solved